# Gulp only executes last task in gulpfile?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-uglify

I have about six Gulp tasks which are similar to this:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'public_html/assets/plugins/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.min.js',
        'public_html/assets/plugins/redactor/redactor.min.js',
        'public_html/assets/libraries/autobahn.min.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('localStatic.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/assets/dist/js/'))
        .pipe(rename('localStatic.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/assets/dist/js'));
});
```

When I run `gulp` in the terminal, it only executes the last task (or at least, only the JS files from the last task are generated).

Multiple tasks are allowed in Gulp, right? Why would only the last task in the file be executed?

Comment: do you have your gulp "default" task at the bottom of gulpfile.js where you list all of your tasks you want to run as default with "gulp" command? something like :

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'scripts', 'images']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple tasks at the same time yes, provided they have different names.

```
gulp.task('name', function() {})
gulp.task('of', function() {})
// ... task definitions
gulp.task('default', ['name', 'of', 'the', 'tasks', 'you', 'want', 'to','run']);
```

This will run all the tasks specified in parallel when you run the `gulp` command.

You can read more about task dependencies in the [docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-deps-fn)

Comment: I just realized tasks need to have unique names. I had all the tasks named `scripts` and so apparently only the last one was executed.

Comment: Oh yeah, that you can't do :)